# json_encode an empty array used in javascript gives an empty array but if json_enode is done on array with some values, it gives object?

Tags: javascript, php

So, What I have done is I have an empty array.

```
$text['test'] = array();
echo json_encode($text)
```

If I json_encode it. The result is
 {"test":[]}

If I use this in javascript, it is treated as array.
If there is some values in the array

```
$text['test'] = array('1' =>'abc');
echo json_encode($text);
```

The output is

```
{"test":{"1":"abc"}}
```

And this is treated as an object in javascript. How to do that in both the case I recieve an object not array or vice versa?? The values in array($text['test'] ) is dynamic.

Comment: can you tell me where is the javascript array?

Comment: I have used the javascript array in php file
like
<script type="text/javascript">

var data = <?php echo json_encode($text);?>;

</script>

Comment: Do it like this--> echo json_encode($text['test']); , if this works please let me know by up voting this comment ;)

Comment: @SagarGuhe: The problem remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

That is how json_encode serialises arrays. If it is a numerically and continously indexed array it will serialise it as a json array. If the array has non numeric or numeric but not continuous indexes then it will serialise it as an object to keep the indexes properly.

Comment: Yes. But is there any way so I don't have to do further checking to find out whether it is an array or object.

Answer (score 0):

Because the keys in your array don't start at `0`, PHP's `json_encode` outputs the result as an object.

To get an array, use `0` as your first index:

```
$text['test'] = array('0' =>'abc');
```

Or better yet:

```
$text['test'] = array('abc');
```

...and continuing your indexes sequentially. The easiest way may be to add the entries individually:

```
$text['test'] = array();
$text['test'][] = 'abc';
$text['test'][] = 'def';
```

Or

```
$text['test'] = array('abc', 'def');
```

Comment: Yes, starting with 0 makes it an array. Thanks...But I can't start the array index with 0, as even the key of an array is dynamic and will be random and it will not be 0 in any case. Can you suggest any other solution for that??

Comment: @Garima: JSON only gives you the two choices here: Either it's an array, which means the keys are implied, start with 0, and continue consecutively; or it's an object, the keys must be given explicitly, and can be any string. There's no way, in JSON, to represent an array with keys that don't start at 0, or sparse arrays. You'll need to ensure that what you're serializing ends up as a JSON array, or you'll have to handle an object at the receiving end. Side note: In the JavaScript that receives this, if you use an object, you can get an array of its keys using `Object.keys`; might be useful.

Comment: Yes, I Have used that:- Object.keys . But I am getting an error when the array is empty. I am getting  "test is not a object". When  it is not empty, every thing works fine. Btw thanks for the explanation..:)

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't Javascript but how PHP treats arrays and hashes. In PHP, an array like

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3);
```

is treated like an array. But when you create an *array* with keys;

```
$arr = array("hello" => "world");
```

it implicitly becomes a hash. This is indeed strange and causes issues like the one you're talking about here.

In Javascript, however, the difference is quite clear:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

is an array; and

```
{hello: "world"}
```

is an object.

Comment: *"an array cannot have keys"* That's not actually true: `var a = []; a.foo = "bar"; console.log(a.foo);` shows `"bar"`. Normal JavaScript arrays [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html), they're just objects backed by `Array.prototype` with special behaviors for a class of properties we call "elements" and a special `length` property. Like all objects, can have arbitrary keys as well as their special class of keys we call "indexes." Now *JSON*, on the other hand, is much more limited wrt arrays.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder point taken, that was a mistake. I'll make the edits.

Answer (score 0):

Associative array always output as object. Clearly specified here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

Following is an associative array:

```
    $text['test'] = array('1' =>'abc');
```

PHP json_encode always outputs associative arrays as object:

```
    {"test":{"1":"abc"}}
```

You can use javascript Array literals instead:

```
    var text = [“abc”];
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick Fix: Simply modify one line in your code

Change this:

```
  echo json_encode($text);
```

To:

```
  echo json_encode($text.test);
```

'test' is property of 'text' object that you can access using '.' operator